# How to create custom stamp in Stamps in Task like Title : "Unavailable" Stamp: UA Using Plangrid API?

Tags: asp.net-core

[PlanGrid snap short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKGT7.png)

I want to create custom stamp  in Stamps in Task like Title : "Unavailable" Stamp: UA Using PlanGrid API but I didn't find anything on [PlanGrid](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have reviewed PlanGrid's API documentation URL but didn't find anything.